# Sorting data and its children using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have data. There are other data of the same type that have children in this data. I want to sort them all according to their 'id' fields, but I couldn't set up the algorithm scheme for it.

What I've tried:

```
const sortedData: [] = [];

function sortAscending(datas: Group[]) {
    sortedData.push(datas.sort((group1, group2) => group1.id - group2.id ));
    return sortedData;
}
```

With this code, I can only sort without children.

**I tried to model the picture I wanted to describe:**
[image]

Note: The returned data will be mapped and used later.

**Sample array:**

```
    0:
      children: [{…}]
      id: 1
      name: "name1"
      [[Prototype]]: Object
    1:
      children: []
      id: 7
      name: "name2"
      [[Prototype]]: Object
```

The 'children' field also has 'children', 'id' and 'name' fields just like themselves. What I want is to sort both the data itself and the data in the children field in it according to their 'id' fields.

Comment: Just as a note, shorten ur sort return by writing  (group1.id - group2.id),  there is no need to make it an if statement

Comment: Please provide a sample array and expected output after the sort array

Comment: I provided your requests @MaximilianDolbaum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to know that array `sort` method sorts the array `in-place` it means it changes the array you pass to it. so

```
const rawData= [...] // your raw, un-sorted data

function sortAscending(data){...} // your function that does sorting

sortAscending(rawData) // after this, your array gets sorted 'in-place'
```

second, if your data has children and those children have their own children and you want them all be sorted ascending you need to write some `recursive` algorithm.
for example:

```
function sortAscending(data){
  data.sort((group1, group2) => group1.id - group2.id));
  for(group of data){
     if (group.children.length) sortAscending(group.children);
  }
}
```